# How can you configure python outline mode in VS Code to show only classes and methods

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

The outline mode for python is a little un-useful, because in addition to showing classes and their "member attributes" (the methods), it shows the attributes of methods (and functions) which is just every variable assigned in a method or function.  Showing these renders the outline view very verbose and not really much of an outline at all.  It also shows all the imports in the module, which again is really not the point of an outline.

Is there any way to configure Python mode in VSCode so that the outline only shows classes, functions and methods?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[VS Code 1.40](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_40#_type-filters-for-outline-and-breadcrumbs) adds the ability to filter the Outline view. Search for settings like `"outline.showVariables"` to see all the options.

Comment: "outline.showModules" is the setting to show/hide imports

Comment: @RyanTarpine `"outline.showModules" : false` still shows imported functions.

Comment: @MarioMey yuck, you're right. and it looks like imported classes are shown too unless you set `outline.showClasses` to false (which'll hide your own classes too). well, I guess that's a reason to stick to Google's style guide which says only import packages and modules ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @MarioMey actually I just installed the pylance extension and now I don't see any imports at all, even when all the `outline.show*` settings are set to true

Comment: @RyanTarpine yes, dude, thanks! You should write this suggestion as an answer ;).

Comment: Oh, this extension does not work well with my code. Now, I have lots of alerts that they shouldn't be there. Well, I'll keep on waiting a native solution.

Answer (score 0):

There does not seem to be.  The ms-python.python extension could provide a feature to control how the outline is displayed by the outline in vscode.  It does not currently do so.  There is a feature request to provide this, https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/6812, but it is apparently awaiting further discussion.

Comment: You could also provide a feature request on VS Code itself as the extension provides the data to VS Code and then it populates the outline view.

Comment: @BrettCannon I guess I think it more appropriate for the request to be on vscode-python since how "python code" exposes and customizes the outline view depends on things specific to the python language.  Similarly "Go" or "haskell" might have different ways of generating and customizing  the outline.  I was putting this on stackoverflow to see if ANYONE had enough interest to upvote the issue.  Personally I've just been turning off outline view because it's just noise to me as it stands for python code.

Comment: the reason I suggested potentially upstream is underneath it all those icons have semantic meaning, so VS Code filter on that level of concept as well. But yes, the extension itself could potentially control it on its own.

Comment: Continuing to use SO comments in a completely inappropriate fashion :-). To solve the problem on vscode becomes the generic problem "for all languages ever".  And in one (all) of those language communities there is some pedant who thinks the right way to model the settings is with an ontology (or something) of "software engineering elements", with a mapping from...    Won't ever happen, or not real soon.  I just want some simple json only setting.  If I had some time, I'd even submit a pull request, because it could be fun to play in the code base...  But, thanks for considering.

Comment: VS Code 1.40.1 has now added this feature for all languages (as @BrettCannon is certainly aware)

Comment: It's funny, vscode did exactly that, created a (probably existing, of course) ontology of "software engineering elements": function-symbols, event-symbols...  Now the language support folks have to decide if something is a 'field-symbol' or a 'property-symbol', and for end user devs it all may not be that clear, but it makes python outline usable. Yay!