# In Python editors in VS Code, can I get code cells (#%%) as top hierarchy in the Outline View?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I read this.
[How can you configure python outline mode in VS Code to show only classes and methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58202760/how-can-you-configure-python-outline-mode-in-vs-code-to-show-only-classes-and-me)

But VS Code 1.40.0 can not do yet. Spyder can do nearly, but I want to use VS Code.
What I want to do is only one.

Can I somehow make VS Code show

```
    # %% Top hierarchy
    def abc():

    # %% Top hierarchy
    def xyz():
```

as

```
 Top hierarchy
   abc
 Top hierarchy
   xyz
```

in outline ?

Or should I wait for next version?

Answer (score 4):

This has been raised as a feature request at [TOC for .py files with percent markup #17218](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/17218). Give it a thumbs up to show support for it and [increase its prioritization](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/17218#issuecomment-956885008), and subscribe to it to get notified about discussion and progress. Please avoid making noisy comments like "+1" / "bump".

Side note that if you're looking for cells to be in the outline for actual notebooks in VS Code, put `"notebook.outline.showCodeCells": true,` in your [settings.json file](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settingsjson).

Answer (score 3):

Hey KennylSHIMURA (I'm a developer on the VSCode Python Extension),

The outline explorer in Spyder functions differently from the Outline window in VS Code. Both IDEs have the concept of code cells (areas of code marked by # %%). But in VS Code they are just used for navigating inside the file and in submitting blocks to the Interactive Window. They do not show up in the Outline window. If you want, you could suggest this on our github page here as a suggestion:

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python