Displaying code cell headers in the Outline in Visual Studio Code
For python code containing cells defined using the '# %%' comment style header, I'm trying to display the list of the cells in the Outline but I can't find an option in Visual Studio Code to do this. I note that such cell headers would be displayed in the Outline in Spyder.
E.g.:
def main():

# %% My First Cell Header
code here

# %% Another Cell Header
more code here 

Based on the above code, the outline should show:
main
   My First Cell Header
   Another Cell Header

In Preferences > Settings, I reviewed all of the available options but didn't find anything that would trigger Outline to display cell headers.
Visual Studio Code version 1.84.0

Looking at the docs, this doesn't seem to be possible. You could make a feature request here :)

maybe related? https://stackoverflow.com/q/71032944/11107541 or not. or maybe https://stackoverflow.com/q/58767627/11107541 (similar, but I don't think exact dup)

BTW, why are you showing the cells nested under main()? Semantically, they're not. You can use Markdown headers if you want to nest things. It'd also help clarify to give main() a body, like just ....
